# How can i show single route for multiple destinations using google maps in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

Let's say I have a list of 3 locations - A, B and C, I am trying find the shortest driving distance between each of the locations in one go:

A to B
A to C
B to A
B to C
C to A
C to B

I need this for 100 different locations, and I am trying to find the best way to get this information. If this issue has to be broken down, then I need a way to find
A to B
A to C

and separately for B to A, B to C, and separately for C to A, C to B.

Comment: Do not know if maps api provides a service for this but its a very well known problem of information technology. Its called the travelling salesman problem. A difficult problem as its in NP. Read more on it. At least if I understand you want to find the shortest route.

Comment: You need to clarify your question and show what you've tried. E.g. what problem are you trying to solve? I'd guess shortest path (if so lookup Dijkstra), @Blackbam has gone for TSP.  Or maybe it's more a Google API question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closet thing to what you are looking for is the Distance Matrix API. Please see the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start

Note that this definitely isn't exactly what you are looking for, but it's the closest thing that Google provides. See example request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC|Houston,TX|New+York+City,NY&destinations=Washington,DC|Houston,TX|New+York+City,NY&key=MY_API_KEY

This will give you the distances from all origins to all destinations. For it to work with your use case, you will need to have the origins and destinations be identical as in my example above. In my example the API returns the following:

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA", "Houston, TX, USA", "New York, NY, USA" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA", "Houston, TX, USA", "New York, NY, USA" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "1 ft",
              "value" : 0
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "1 min",
              "value" : 0
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "1,408 mi",
              "value" : 2266226
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "20 hours 22 mins",
              "value" : 73331
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "225 mi",
              "value" : 361722
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "3 hours 48 mins",
              "value" : 13672
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "1,409 mi",
              "value" : 2266981
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "20 hours 28 mins",
              "value" : 73678
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "1 ft",
              "value" : 0
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "1 min",
              "value" : 0
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "1,628 mi",
              "value" : 2620605
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "23 hours 44 mins",
              "value" : 85438
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "226 mi",
              "value" : 364085
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "3 hours 53 mins",
              "value" : 13965
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "1,627 mi",
              "value" : 2618345
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "23 hours 43 mins",
              "value" : 85385
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        },
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "1 ft",
              "value" : 0
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "1 min",
              "value" : 0
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

You can see that the distance from all thee locations to all three locations is successfully returned. Please keep in mind the usage limits of this API as well:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits

With a standard project, you can have a maximum of 100 elements per request. Note that to get elements you multiply number of origins by the number of destinations. With a standard project you can have 10 destination and 10 origins. That being said, you won't be able to do this for 100 locations in a single request. You will need to do the locations in batches of 10, unless you have a premium project. With a premium project you could follow the same logic, but use 25 locations at the same time.

I just wanted to let you know the closest solution I could think of to what you are looking for. I hope this helps!